# showing icon corresponding to filetype in ractive in a simple way

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

For a node application I have a list of uploaded files shown with Ractive which works great so far. One of the fields I use is the Filetype (in my Data stored as extension e.g. `FileType: pptx`).

In my ractive Template I'd like to show a corresponding Image to the type of File uploaded for visual aid, but that tends to end in an endless if-statement.

So for now the template looks (simplified) like

```
'<span class="fa 
{{#if FileType == "pptx" || FileType == "ppt" || FileType == "ppts" || //going on here forever}}
    fa-file-powerpoint-o
{{elseif FileType == "xls" || FileType == "xlsx" || ...}}
    fa-file-excel-o
//then the same follows for Videos, Word, pdf, ...
{{else}}
    fa fa-file-o
{{/if}} 
"></span>'
```

Does anybody know a decent way to shorten that horrible piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to have a mapping of extension -> class stored in your data at e.g. `~/fileType`. So `{ ppt: 'fa-file-powerpoint-o', pptx: 'etc' }` could then be used in the template as `class="fa {{~/fileType[FileType] || 'fa-file-o'}}"`.

You could shrink the data a bit by shipping a list of list of name -> type e.g.

```
const types = [[['ppt', 'pptx', 'ppty', 'pptz'],'fa-file-powerpoint-o'], [['exe'], 'fa-file-boom']]
const map = {};
types.forEach(entry => entry[0].forEach(extension => map[extension] = entry[1]));
this.set('fileType', map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the best way to tackle that particular problem is by using a database.

So you can add a record for a specified icon and assign multiple extensions to it.  Then retrieve a dataset with all records and just loop through it and check for that field containing that extension.

And then of course you can set a 'default' record that will show a default icon.

And as a plus, if you only need to make one comparison, that logic execution can be handed off to the DBMS server in the SELECT query.

**EDIT:**

I realise now the 'database' would have to be client side.

*So instead just use a xml file.*

Comment: I do use a Client side Database, but it is noSQL which is not very suitable for this kind of storage. But the idea of storing the variables outside the template is appealing. Maybe a computed value in ractive?

Comment: You see, as  I see it, this type of problem needs a dataset.  Hardcoding it would be very messy to maintain....At least IMHO

Comment: I haven't worked with ractive, but I don't think this problem will be solved with it.  You will likely end up using some JS solution.  I still vote on an XML dataset.  Parsing and looping through XML is also extremely simple and intuitive.